# specify injections for child classes

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I've got an abstract class that has injectable field

```
public abstract class AbstractPopulator implements ITemplatePopulator {
    @Inject
    private ITemplatePopulator next;
```

I have multiple classes that inherit `AbstractPopulator`. They are simple in a sense

```
public class ImportsPopulator extends AbstractPopulator
public class FieldsPopulator extends AbstractPopulator 
public class LeftHandSidePopulator extends AbstractPopulator
```

But I need for each of them to have their own injected `next` field. For example for `leftHandSide` I want `righthandside` and so on.

How to achieve that using `google guice`?

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, I decided to do this.
In `AbstractPopulator` I added abstract method `injectNext`

```
protected abstract void injectNext(ITemplatePopulator next);
```

and removed `@Inject` annotation for the field `next` itself.

In each child class I implemented this method like this

```
@Override
@Inject
protected void injectNext(@Named("rightHandSidePopulator") ITemplatePopulator next) {
    setNext(next);
}
```

where I specified via `@Named` the name of the next populator in the chain of responsibility.

The last one populator is special

```
@Override
@Inject(optional = true)
protected void injectNext(@Named("null") ITemplatePopulator next) {
    setNext(next);
}
```

I set the `optional` parameter of `Inject` annotation to true because according to `Guice` documentation

> Method and field injections may be optional, which causes Guice to silently 
>   ignore them when the dependencies aren't available

So if no object with `null` name found it won't wire `next`.

In the module class, I bound classes

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(ITemplatePopulator.class)
            .annotatedWith(Names.named("packageNamePopulator")).to(PackageNamePopulator.class);
...
```

And `guice` used it like this where needed

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new PopulatorModule());
ITemplatePopulator first = injector.getInstance(PackageNamePopulator.class); // first in chain
```

It seems to be working ok, but I am not sure whether it is the best solution and annotation imports are

```
import com.google.inject.Inject;
import com.google.inject.name.Named;
```